# Is there a way to display when Wifi/Data is being used on the Google Pixel?

Tags: wi-fi, settings, mobile-data, google-pixel

I've just recently switched over from an LG G3 to a Google Pixel and I've noticed a slight change in the top status bar between the two phones.

On the G3, both the Wifi and Data icons showed little arrows to indicate when data was being transferred (see picture below, the arrows have been circled in red):

[image: LG G3]

**These same arrows are not there on the Google Pixel, is there a way to display them?**

***Note:*** *These arrows are visible if you pull the top menu down (see picture below) so the feature does exist. I'm just not sure if it can be enabled when the menu is **not** pulled down.*

[image]

Comment: If I recall correctly, they pulled the ability to see activity in the notification bar in favor of when it's pulled down from vanilla Android back in version 4-something. That your LG showed it is almost certainly a customization added by LG.

Comment: It looks like there might be some apps in the Play Store that will show the activity in the status bar.